# infinite fetching api in internal api

Tags: next.js

hello i'm get in this trouble when i want to fetching my user role from my api and check it while user is loaded i got a inifinite loop call request, here my code

```
export const Layout = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const { user, error, isLoading } = useUser();
  const [role, setRole] = React.useState(''); // ['admin', 'user']
  const router = useRouter();

  const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [_, setLocked] = useLockedBody(false);
  const handleToggleSidebar = () => {
    setSidebarOpen(!sidebarOpen);
    setLocked(!sidebarOpen);
  };

  const getUserRole = (username) => {
    fetch(`api/accounts/getAccountByUsername?username=${username}`, {
      headers: {
        'X-Authorization': "YXRoaWZhYXJlemE6YXJlemFhdGhpZmE=",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const dataUser = data['data'];

        // console.log("duarr")
        setRole(dataUser)
        // return(dataUser)
      })
  }


  if (isLoading) {
    return <div></div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>{error.message}</div>;
  }


  if (user && !isLoading) {
    // getUserRole(user.email)  <---------- when i call this infinite fetching api called
    // console.log("kontolll")

    return (
      <SidebarContext.Provider
        value={{
          collapsed: sidebarOpen,
          setCollapsed: handleToggleSidebar,
        }}
      >
        <section className="flex">
          <SidebarWrapper />
          <NavbarWrapper>{children}</NavbarWrapper>
        </section>
      </SidebarContext.Provider>
    )

    if (role != null) {
      if (role['level'] === 'admin') {
       
      }
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        router.push('/api/auth/logout'); // Delete session jika user tidak memiliki role
        return null;
      }, 5000);
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
        </div>
      )
    }

  }
  if (!user) {
    router.push('/api/auth/login'); // Delete session jika user tidak memiliki role
    return null;
  }
};
```

Is there an error in calling a function? Or am I wrong in creating the fetch data function?

Please enlighten me, am I wrong in summoning fire or what?

I have tried to store the value in a variable and tried to fetch it after I got the user but I still experience infinite fetch api

Comment: I did a quick search and I I think it's endless looping because you're using a render function. It re-renders itself every time you call the function, which in turns calls the function again.

Comment: @Fusseldieb said very well, It re-renders itself every time.
  the **getUserRole** function should be in  **useEffect** .. it only render when page load.